# C++ Program cannot see mapped drives

Tags: mapped-drive

I am coding an unmanaged C++ console application on Windows 7 using Visual Studio 2010.  I ran into an issue where files on my local computer or a network location work fine, but my code can't see anything on a mapped drive.  I can simply this issue to a program that is the following 2 lines:

const WCHAR * libPath = _T("L:\MyFiles\myfile.txt");
DWORD fa = GetFileAttributes(libPath);

Where fa comes back as 0xFFFFFFFF, L is a mapped drive, and L:\MyFiles\myfile.txt is a valid text file.

How do I access mapped drives?

Comment: That return value is INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES. What does GetLastError() give you when this fails ? Also, you should use \\ to escape a \ as in _T("L:\\MyFiles\\myfile.txt");, do you have that in your real code ?

Comment: GetLastError gives me 3, which is "The system cannot find the path specified."

Comment: I have tried \\ as well as \ as well as other combinations.

Comment: I am on 64-bit Windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with Visual Studio.  "Start without debugging" is NOT the same as running from explorer on Windows 7.  The program works fine started from Windows Explorer.  This is due to different UAC rights.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that your application is running in elevated mode (ie. with `Run as administrator` selected). The problem is discussed in greater detail [here](http://www.winability.com/how-to-make-elevated-programs-recognize-network-drives/).

The solution is to use `net use` to mount the drive or merge this into your registry:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"EnableLinkedConnections"=dword:00000001
```

Note that a reboot is required after making the above change.